# Issue with creating additional contact forms - recaptcha

Tags: php, cms, magento-1.6, forms, contact-us

I'm trying to create an additional contact form and am running into an issue - initially I modified the default contacts form but ran into issues so tried just using the default contact form on a CMS page, using the following code:

```
{{block type='core/template' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```

but whenever I try to submit the form it produces the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object in /home/urider/web/app/code/community/Fontis/Recaptcha/controllers/ContactsController.php on line 32
```

line 31,32 is as follows:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
```

From what I've seen online it may be something to do with the layout not being loaded but I'm really not sure, any thoughts?

Comment: try extension https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 2):

Just change form action in full format:

remove this code: `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') )`

```
Change form action: `action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post') ?> "`
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, is there any potential for this screwing anything up in the future?  Edit: I just tried this and it broke the contact form on the /contactus/ page (it produced the same error that was occurring on the cms page contact form)

Comment: form.phtml file change the action to  Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')

Comment: Hey Amit,  Sorry I should have added, it didn't fix the original problem anyway, the form action in both contact forms is: "<?php echo $this->getFormAction() ? $this->getFormAction() : '/contacts/index/post/'; ?>"

Comment: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')?>" just do this .. no need to set <?php echo $this->getFormAction() ? $this->getFormAction() : '/contacts/index/post/'; ?>

Comment: Sorry it's still producing the same fatal error for both contact forms

Comment: are you remove this code: $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );

Comment: Hey Amit, I'm changing it as recommended in your original post

Comment: Hey Amit,  I have tried just removing the $this->... as you suggested, the error no longer displays, but I just get taken to a blank page and the normal contact form no longer sends the messages through to our email account

Comment: check now.I was not some silly mistake.... for php code

Comment: Hey Amit, what has been changed?  I can't see any difference in what you were recommending the form action changing to

Comment: can you please show your phtml code?

Comment: How much of it do you need to see...?  Here's the form initialiser  <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction() ? $this->getFormAction() : '/contacts/index/post/'; ?>" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">